# Remove rows that are near duplicate of previous row in Deedle dataframe

Tags: f#, dataframe, f#-data, deedle

I have a **Deedle** Data frame that looks like this.

```
val it : Frame<int,string> =
          Date                        size1 size2 
13     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.103336Z 133   35    
14     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.105184Z 83    35    
15     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.107205Z 83    35    
16     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.109566Z 83    34    
17     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.115260Z 83    34    
18     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.133546Z 83    34    
20     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.138204Z 82    34    
22     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.140125Z 81    34
```

I would like to remove rows that have the same values for **both** size1 and size2 as the previous row. In pseudo code...

```
if row?size1 = prevRow?size1 && row?size2 = prevRow?size2 then dropRow
```

So in the example above I would end up with:

```
val it : Frame<int,string> =
          Date                        size1 size2 
13     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.103336Z 133   35    
14     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.105184Z 83    35    
16     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.109566Z 83    34    
20     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.138204Z 82    34    
22     -> 2013-12-12T00:00:00.140125Z 81    34
```

I believe I want to use

```
Frame.filterRowValues(row - > )
```

But I don't see how to compare one row against the previous row. Is there a simple way to do this? Perhaps I need to shift and join?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using a number of ways and I'm not quite sure which is the best one:

- Use shift and join (as you say) would certainly work - you'd need to rename the columns in one of the frames so that you can join them, but it sounds like quite a good solution to me
- You can use `frame.Rows |> Series.pairwise` to get tuples containing the current and the previous row, then use `Series.filter` and `Series.map` (to select the second row from the tuple) and re-construct frame using `Frame.ofRows`. The only issue is that you'll always lost the first row this way (and you'll have to add it back).
- You can use `Frame.filter` and find the previous row. The recent release supports `Lookup.Smaller` which lets you do that easily.

The code for the third option looks like this (note that the frame rows need to be ordered `frame.Rows.IsOrdered = true`) for this to work:

```
frame |> Frame.filterRows (fun k row ->
  let prev = frame.Rows |> Series.tryLookup k Lookup.Smaller // New in v1.0
  match prev with 
  | Some prev -> prev?Something <> row?Something
  | _ -> true (* always return true for the first row *) )
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that the frame is not ordered. The problem is that the data is already in order according to date, but has duplicates dates so ordering fails with a duplicate key error

Comment: Ah, but if the index is integer, then it would be ordered (which is the case in your sample output). You could make sure that's the case using `Frame.indexRowsOrdinally` (which replaces the current index with increasing, ordered, integers). Would that work?